# Flutter autofill not working with latest SDK

Tags: flutter, input, autofill, form-fields

I'm working on a form in which I want to have the functionality for autofill.

Unfortunately, I'm trying to use the `AutofillGroup` widget with `TextField` or `TextFormField` with *autofillHints* setup but they don't work on both **emulator** and **real device**.

I'm using Flutter *SDK 2.10.0*

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutofillGroup(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(controller: username, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.username]),
          Checkbox(
            value: isNewUser,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              setState(() { isNewUser = newValue; });
            },
          ),
          if (isNewUser) TextField(controller: newPassword, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword]),
          if (isNewUser) TextField(controller: repeatNewPassword, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword]),
          if (!isNewUser) TextField(controller: password, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AutofillGroup(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                  controller: username,
                  autofillHints: [AutofillHints.username]),
              TextFormField(
                  controller: newPassword,
                  autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```